# Zend_Test: No default module defined for this application

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-test

### UPDATE 23 Dec

I had the problem where Zend Framework complains about "No default module defined for this application". I didn't use Modules and the main app works fine.

I finally solved the problem with the help from [weierophinney.net](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/182-Testing-Zend-Framework-MVC-Applications.html#c22838)

> Your bootstrap needs to minimally set the controller directory -- do a call to `$this->frontController->addControllerDirectory(...)` in your `appBootstrap()` method. I didn't in my example, as my Initialization plugin does that sort of thing for me.

The problem is solved by adding the below to `setUp()`

```
$this->getFrontController()->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers');
```

But now, I have afew other questions:

**1. Why does that value not get initialized by `application.ini`?**

In `application.ini`, I have

```
[production]
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"

[testing : production]
// didn't change anything regarding modules nor controllers
```

**2. I tried setting the `controllerDirectory` in `bootstrap.php` of my unit test, but it does not work**

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers');
```

The only way that works is using `setUp()`. Why is that?

**END UPDATE 23 Dec**

---

I am getting the above error when unit testing my controller plugins. I am not using any modules. in my bootstrap.php for unit testing, I even tried adding

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setDefaultModule('default');
```

But it still does not work. Anyways my bootstrap.php looks like **[this](http://pastebin.com/HPYjMbbL)**

**UPDATE**: the error looks something like

There were 2 errors:

```
1) Application_Controller_Plugin_AclTest::testAccessToUnauthorizedPageRedirectsToLogin
Zend_Controller_Exception: No default module defined for this application

D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:391
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:204
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:244
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Front.php:954
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\ControllerTestCase.php:205
D:\Projects\Tickle\tests\application\controllers\plugins\aclTest.php:6

2) Application_Controller_Plugin_AclTest::testAccessToAllowedPageWorks
Zend_Controller_Exception: No default module defined for this application

D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:391
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:204
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:244
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Controller\Front.php:954
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\ControllerTestCase.php:205
D:\Projects\Tickle\tests\application\controllers\plugins\aclTest.php:16
```

**UPDATE**

I tried adding

```
public function setUp() {
  $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $front->setDefaultModule('default');
}
```

then 1 part works.

```
public function testAccessToUnauthorizedPageRedirectsToLogin() { // this fails with exception "Zend_Controller_Exception: No default module defined for this application"
  $this->dispatch('/projects');
  $this->assertController('auth');
  $this->assertAction('login');
}

public function testAccessToAllowedPageWorks() { // this passes
  $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
  $authAdapter = new Application_Auth_Adapter('jiewmeng', 'password');
  $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

  $this->dispatch('/projects');
  $this->assertController('projects');
  $this->assertAction('index');
}
```

Comment: could you please post the error msg

Comment: Try to do: var_dump($this->getResponse->getBody()); i think the error controller is fired and will tell you whats wrong.

Comment: @ArneRie, I got `Call to undefined method Zend_Controller_Request_HttpTestCase::getBody()`

Comment: for your 1st test try ($this->assertRedirect('/auth/login');)

Comment: @ArneRie, I still got the same error ... It seems weird that the 2nd test passes ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution it seems is to have this is `setUp()`.

```
$this->getFrontController()->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers');
```

Tho I am still looking for answers to my questions posted in the update

> **1. Why does that value not get initialized by application.ini?**
>
> In `application.ini`, I have
>
> ```
> [production]
> resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
>
> [testing : production]
> // didn't change anything regarding modules nor controllers
> ```
>
> **2. I tried setting the `controllerDirectory` in
>   `bootstrap.php` of my unit test, but
>   it does not work**
>
> ```
> $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
> $front->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH
> ```
>
> . '/controllers');
>
> The only way that works is using
>   `setUp()`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but this did not solve the error at all. Neither in the setUp() method nor in a plugin. But setting the bootstrap resource solved it although it is normaly set by my application. In my case the following worked:

```
if($this->getFrontController()->getParam('bootstrap') === null) {
    $this->getFrontController()->setParam('bootstrap', $app->getBootstrap());
}
```